# Cleanup needed: [react-create-app] mistags for [create-react-app]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The primary method of creating a React app is [create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/create-react-app) (CRA) with 4,543 questions.

I came across 86 questions tagged with [react-create-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-create-app) (RCA) and it seems like most of them are mistakes. But there does exist an [obscure npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-create-app) with that name so it's possible that a few are genuine.  Many of the questions tagged with RCA explicitly mention CRA so those can be retagged.  I'm not sure if the others should be left alone or if the tags should be synonymized.

Comment: A [search for `[react-create-app] "create-react-app"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Breact-create-app%5D+%22create-react-app%22) returns 50 of the 86 questions, and there's almost certainly more.

Comment: The obscure npm package you mention was last active 4 years ago. The links in the README are all broken, there's no documentation, and the package doesn't generate an app like CRA does, it simply [exports an `App` component which is very unwieldy to work with](https://unpkg.com/browse/react-create-app@2.0.6/src/index.js). I highly suspect any activity on the package can be dismissed as people mistyping `npx create-react-app` in their terminal.

Comment: I barely remember any frontend developer that wouldn't do this mistake at least once. Such an unfortunate naming.