# What is the difference between [create-react-app] and [react-create-app]? Should the latter be aliased to the former?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

While reviewing a first question I stumbled across the following two tags:

1. [create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/create-react-app) 5,360 questions

   > create-react-app is a starter-kit for creating React applications with no build configuration. If you’re getting started with React, use this to automate the build of your application. There isn't any configuration file, and react-scripts is the only extra build dependency in your package.json file. Your environment will have everything you need to build a modern React application.
   >
   > [Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/getting-started).
2. [react-create-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-create-app) 80 questions

   Tag excerpt:

   > Use this tag for questions regarding the react-create-app command.

   Tag info:

   > `create-react-app` allows anyone with Node and npm to create their own React web application.
   >
   > From the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) > [Create a New React App](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html),
   >
   > > ```
   > > npx create-react-app my-app
   > > cd my-app
   > > npm start
   > > ```
   >
   > scaffolds a front-end web application that you can start using immediately.

The tag excerpt for [react-create-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-create-app) makes it sound like it is distinct from [create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/create-react-app), but the full tag info suggests that they are the same.  And [Create a New React App](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app) links to [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) which seems to be the same thing as [Getting Started](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/).

Are these tags in fact the same?  Should [react-create-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-create-app) be aliased to [create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/create-react-app)?

Comment: It *looks* like `react-create-app` is a typo, or possibly created because someone thought it would be easier to find with the tag suggestions/autocompletion after typing `react`. I should think it's easy enough to test the theory, by installing Node and whatever else is needed to make `npx`/`npm` commands work, and then seeing if `npx react-create-app` does anything.

Comment: They're one and the same. (aka react-create-app is an incorrect name for the command users intend by it)

Comment: This has come up once before: [Cleanup needed: \[react-create-app\] mistags for \[create-react-app\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408103). When that was originally posted, there was, in fact, an obscure "react-create-app" package, but it looks like that has [since disappeared](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-create-app). I think these tags can likely be merged without any issue at this point.

Comment: @zcoop98 - huh, that didn't show up as a possibly related question. But it certainly is!  Anyway, if [tag:react-create-app] is or was ever a tagworthy thing whose questions need to be preserved, can the tag info be updated?

Comment: If it ever was, which I'm skeptical of, that is *certainly* not how it's being used now.  A [search for `[react-create-app] -"create-react-app" is:q`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Breact-create-app%5D+-%22create-react-app%22+is%3Aq&searchOn=1) turns up only 49 questions, and a handful I've spot-checked make it clear they meant the `create-react-app` command.

Comment: @RyanM - feel like we should alias then.  But I'm not a SME so what buy-in is required to make it happen?

Comment: I can create a synonym tomorrow and merge later if there are no objections. However, I think it would be good to go through the 49 questions and verify if it's a typo, fixing the typo in the process. I don't think we are going to find a single question worth keeping the tag for.

Comment: I can volunteer to do some of that work, but that sort of sounds like burnination so is it OK to begin?

Comment: @RyanM your search is catching a little high. because it's also catching questions where [create-react-app is in code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56089305/1) markdown. It'd be nice to be able to exclude both "create-react-app" or `create-react-app`

Comment: I was considering it a [meta-tag:retag-request] and not a burnination. We're not removing content or mass deleting/closing anything. Retagging a clearly irrelevant tag on a small subset of questions to prepare for a merge should be fine to start. A mod is always welcome to correct me here if I'm wrong.

Comment: @HenryEcker I had actually tried to do that, but it seems that search is incapable of multiple exclusions.  Another post links to a URL containing "create-react-app".

Comment: @RyanM I went through the questions in [your query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Breact-create-app%5D+-%22create-react-app%22+is%3Aq&searchOn=1).  I retagged those for which there was internal textual evidence from the question, the accepted answer, or other comments/answers from the querent, that `create-react-app` was actually used.  There are 39 left.  I think a SME needs to take a look.

Comment: For anyone wanting to retag: if the question mentions `react-scripts` or shows `react-scripts` in the `package.json` then it should be retagged to [tag:create-react-app]

Comment: @Dharman - it's down to 21 questions tagged [tag:react-create-app].  Is that a small enough number to add the alias?

Comment: I inspected the questions again today and I think all remaining 21 questions should be retagged too. I created a synonym now and I will merge it in 2 days.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a lot of discussion in comments.  E.g. [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419264/what-is-the-difference-between-create-react-app-and-react-create-app-should?cb=1#comment918628_419264) by [zcoop98](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/11047824/zcoop98) asserts

> This has come up once before: [Cleanup needed: [react-create-app] mistags for [create-react-app]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408103). When that was originally posted, there was, in fact, an obscure "react-create-app" package, but it looks like that has [since disappeared](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-create-app). I think these tags can likely be merged without any issue at this point.

You [asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc):

> I can volunteer to do some of that work, but that sort of sounds like burnination so is it OK to begin?

For this kind of issue, where you have edit privileges and suspect that eighty questions are tagged incorrectly, it is reasonable to proceed with retagging those questions where you verify that the tag is incorrect.  So if you read a question and decide that in your opinion that [react-create-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-create-app) is incorrect and retag it as [create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/create-react-app), you may certainly do so.  In general, we trust you to make that decision.  If you are unsure, you can simply skip that question or post a meta about it (or even edit your question here to include it).

This isn't a burnination where people are claiming the tag is used correctly but would be better not used.  The claim here is that the questions are simply tagged incorrectly.  You don't need any affirmation of that.  Go ahead and fix it.  If you want to be really safe, post a community wiki answer here with the questions that you retag.  Then it would be easy to tag them back if someone disagreed.

If you (possibly with the help of others) retag all eighty questions, then we would have no reason to continue with the tag.  Just ping [@Dharman](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1839439/dharman) to make the synonym.  If there are some left (because you weren't sure if they could be changed) then people could engage in more discussion.

If you find a question where you think that it really should be tagged react-create-app, then you might post that here as well (perhaps as an answer to this question, possibly as community-wiki so others could add to it).  Then the correct solution might be a change to the tag wiki/excerpt.  Or on further discussion, it might be decided that it's not important enough for its own tag.  But let's wait that discussion until we have examples to discuss.

Comment: This one might actually refer to the now-deleted https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-create-app: [Typescript transpile es6 .js dependency to es5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50090972/3744182): *Context if you care: I made the horrible mistake of using `react-create-app-typescript` and `react-scripts-ts` as the boilerplate for my React app. The webpack stack built in is very opinionated on where source code should come from and that the compiled source must be es5...*

Comment: Unfortunately [`react-create-app`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-create-app) isn't even [archived](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-create-app) so it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: I went through the questions in [RyanM's query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Breact-create-app%5D+-%22create-react-app%22+is%3Aq&searchOn=1).  I retagged those for which there was internal textual evidence from the question, the accepted answer, or other comments/answers from the querent, that `create-react-app` was actually used.  There are 39 left.  I think a SME needs to take a look.

Comment: I just fixed about 25 questions.  When in doubt, I think it's safe to assume that a typo is the most likely explanation.

Comment: @LindaPaiste - *I just fixed about 25 questions.* -- thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I retagged all the [react-create-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-create-app) questions for which there was internal textual evidence that the question was really about [create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/create-react-app).  Linda Paiste retagged all those referring to `react-scripts`.  That leaves 21 questions.  Some of those mention `react-create-app` only in passing, but the following seem to be *about* creating their app with `react-create-app`:

- [Solve collision className of css modules in react-create-app without eject](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60392971/3744182)
- [React create app - How do you import a nested component?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59804948/3744182)
- [React Create App -> Why SASS compiled css variables 2 time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59476901/3744182)
- [React/Webpack: How to make dynamic import/require depend of variable with code cleanup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58913951/3744182)
- [How to get a production build with docker + react-create-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58701453/3744182)
- [Inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58354362/3744182)
- [Moving messages from `content.js` to App.js in react-create-app when creating google-chrome-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58048638/3744182)
- [Create two different outputs from the same file in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58029161/3744182)
- [How to make React Create App Production Error Boundary map to source code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50223991/3744182)
- [Typescript transpile es6 .js dependency to es5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50090972/3744182)

  > Context if you care:
  > I made the horrible mistake of using `react-create-app-typescript` and `react-scripts-ts` as the boilerplate for my React app. The webpack stack built in is very opinionated on where source code should come from and that the compiled source must be es5. The minifier/uglifier packaged will crash if attempting to minify any es6 artifacts. I know I can run `npm run-script eject` and modify the various config scripts but I am trying to avoid that mess. I would love to just get the source to compile to es6 and not mess with their webpack stack.

  (There does not appear to be an npm package `react-create-app-typescript` currently. [`react-scripts-ts`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts-ts) does exist, and references `create-react-app` in its documentation.)
- [Configure production environment for react-create-app at aws elasticbeanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49858753/3744182)
- [How to automatically add import in less from the react app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49653534/3744182)
- [react-create-app static html page in public folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49624732/3744182)
- [Set up D3 with react-create-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48633338/set-up-d3-with-react-create-app)
- [React Deploying to AWS S3 production using npm - index.html file as last](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48341141/3744182)

Of course any and all of these might really be about `create-react-app`, but given that the old `react-create-app` package has been [taken down](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-create-app) and isn't even [archived](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-create-app), it's hard to say for sure in 2022 what it used to do and whether the questions should be retagged; perhaps a SME could do better.

However, **new questions are still being asked using the erroneous tag [react-create-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-create-app)** (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73004316/3744182) from 2 days ago which I fixed) so I think that, despite these 21 questions, the tag should be aliased (or burninated then aliased) so that future questions will be tagged correctly.

Alternatively, the tag info and guidance for [`react-create-app`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/react-create-app/info) should be updated as follows:

> Use this tag only for questions regarding the react-create-app command.  DO NOT USE THIS TAG FOR QUESTIONS ABOUT create-react-app, USE [create-react-app] INSTEAD.

And then the remainder of the guidance (which refers to `create-react-app`) should be deleted.

Comment: If the majority of people do not know what the tag is for and the library cannot be found then why should we keep a highly confusing tag? I will merge it in 2 days. Thanks for retagging.

Comment: That certainly works for me!

Comment: @Dharman thanks for being so decisive on this!  Those of us who aren't mods don't want to overstep so we are overly cautious.  I agree that killing it is the correct decision.  Even when the user explicitly mentions `react-create-app` it's clear that it's not what they meant.  I looked at the "Set up D3 with react-create-app" question linked in this answer, which has a link to a codesandbox, and sure enough it's a create-react-app setup with `react-scripts`.